# Set function's static variable outside function

Tags: php

If we have

```
function counter() {
    static $count = 0;

    $count++;

    return $count;
}
```

can we set value of `$count` outside of function `counter()`?

I know that you can get values of all static variables inside of function with Reflection:

```
$vars = (new ReflectionFunction('counter'))->getStaticVariables()
```

but I can't find simmilar thing for setting.

Answer (score 2):

Wouldn't it be easier to just do the following;

```
$count = 1;

function counter() {
    global $count;

    $count++;

    return $count;
}

die(var_dump(counter()));
```

This way because $count is globally available you can set the value of it to whatever it needs to be on initialisation.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an optional parameter and override the static initialization if it is provided.

```
function counter($init = null) {
    static $count = 0;

    if (!is_null($init)) $count = $init;

    $count++;

    return $count;
}
```